# Apply Stokes theorem on a curve which is intersection of a sphere and plane

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Apply Stokes theorem to prove that $\int_{c} ydx+zdy+xdz =-2\sqrt{2}\pi a^2$
Where C is the curve given by $x^2+y^2+z^2-2ax-2ay=0, x+y=2a$ ; **and begins at the point (2a,0,0) and it goes first below the z plane**.

So, I got F = x$\hat{i}$ + y$\hat{j}$ +z$\hat{k}$ and then I used **-$\int\int_{c} (∇\times F).n ds$** and my answer is coming($2\sqrt{2}\pi a^2$) which is **negative** of what is to prove and i think its correct because they have said the curve goes below z plane first, that means it's oriented in **negative** direction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your work, and precise your question.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

- The equation
  $$
  x^2+y^2+z^2-2ax-2ay=0
  $$
  can be written as
  $$
  (x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+z^2=2a^2
  $$
  and thus describes a sphere around $(a,a,0)$ with radius $r=\sqrt{2}\,|a|\,.$ Your curve $C$ is the intersection of that sphere with the plane
  $$
  x+y=2a
  $$
  which is parallel to the $z$-axis, goes through the center of the sphere and has unit normal vector
  $$
  \mathbf{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
  If you use the right hand rule you see that the orientation of this is compatible with saying that the curve starts at $(2a,0,0)$ and goes below the
  $x$-$y$-plane first.
- The vector field $F=(y,z,x)$ you are supposed to integrate over $C$
  has curl $(-1,-1,-1)\,.$ The dot product of that curl with $\mathbf{n}$ is the negative
  constant $-\sqrt{2}$.
- Stokes tells you that we can integrate that constant over the disk $B$ with radius $r=\sqrt{2}\,|a|\,,$
  center $(a,a,0)$ and lying in the plane $x+y=2a\,:$
  $$
  \int_C F\cdot\,ds=\int_B {\rm curl} F\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS=-\sqrt{2}\,\pi\,r^2=-2\sqrt{2}\,\pi\, a^2\,.
  $$